# “a rabbit’s foot” vs. “the rabbit’s foot”

Tags: definite-articles, indefinite-articles

I’m confused about the use of the indefinite article *a* in the following passage:

> My lucky charm is a rabbit’s foot that I received as a gift on my birthday. I don't really know if it has ever brought me good luck, but I always carry it in my pocket.... People have believed that carrying **a rabbit’s foot** will protect them.

We know that to represent all members of a class or group of people, things, etc. a plural count noun or a singular noun with a definite or an indefinite article may be used. So can I use ***the*** rabbit’s foot instead of *a rabbit’s foot* in the above passage?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

'People have believed that carrying **the rabbit's foot** will protect them.' would mean that they all carried the same exact rabbit's foot. 
Use the indefinite article here, since you talk about these lucky charms in general. So the correct sentence is 'People have believed that carrying **a rabbit's foot** will protect them.'

Other alternative: the foot of a rabbit.